# E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list (Suite)

Tags: scala

I run sudo apt-get update when trying to instal SBT on linux and get this errors

1. E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list (Suite)
2. E: The list of sources could not be read.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have a broken PPA in your source list. Navigate to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and inspect the `additional PPA file`.
This file should contain all manually added PPAs, Delete the PPA causing the problem (Usually the last one you added) or delete the file itself (very dangerous).

Note: Your filesystem may slightly differ and you would also need to open as root to modify the file. If you are good with the command line, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to file: $sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list

The file should contain a single line: deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/

Comment this line out with # and save.

Rerun sudo apt-get update and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar. Only the first line of output said:

`E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list (Suite)`

And the second line was the same as in this problem.

`E: The list of sources could not be read.`

The solution proposed above by our friends is similar and it helped me to solve this. Although I was guided by the following tutorial: https://codepre.com/how-to-add-remove-ppa-repositories-in-debian.html